# Git remoteサーバーにpushされたファイルが見えない

Tags: git

Gitのremoteサーバーを運用したくてAWSのEC2にubuntu linuxをインストール、Gitサーバーを作りました。

Gitサーバーを運用する他の目的としてpushされたソースがApacheにすぐ反映されるため (デプロイ) `/var/www/html` の `git init --bare --shared` して他の端末機からclone, pushができるように設定しました。

この設定の上でユーザーを追加し、試してみたら他のパソコンからcloneやadd, commit pushまでうまくできました。だがEC2のremoteサーバーに接続して確認したところ `/var/www/html` にpushされたファイルが見えないです。(find / 'ファイル名'で検索しても見つけないです。)

さらにもっとおかしいことは他のrepositoryを作ってcloneしたらremotoサーバーの/var/www/htmlには見えないpushされたファイルが普通にcheck outされ、見えます。

ずっとバタバタしながら試していますが、一体何が間違ったかよくわからないです。

懸念としては

1. そもそもApacheのフォルダー (`/var/www/html`) はGitのremote用フォルダーとして使えない。
2. 何か権限の問題か？remote Gitサーバーを設定した時、間違ったことがあったか？

ぐらいです。

もしかして同じような経験をしたことがある方は教えていただけませんか？ よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2):

`git init` に `--bare` オプションを付けた場合は、管理情報のみを持つリポジトリが作成されます。実際の (管理対象の) ファイルが見られるようにしたい場合、`--bare` を付けないでリポジトリを作成してください。

Comment: bareでないリポジトリにpushするには設定が必要ですね http://qiita.com/takoba/items/8026127469e7359cba2e

Comment: ありがとうございます。
非常に助かります！試してみます。